# Pick up photo within registration not working at all

Tags: bug, status-completed, sign-up

There is an option to pick up photo during registration:

> [image: screenshot of registration page]

But if I click on <kbd>Pick a photo</kbd> button, then instead of dialog of selecting photo some strange block is shown:

> [image: screenshot of strange things]

[Screencast on Youtube](https://youtu.be/N-hF-hYFDY4)

Comment: That "strange block" looks like the footer (but very messed up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh hey, now there's an oversight that's gone unnoticed for several weeks. :/

Sorry about that. I pushed a fix, but there are a few other changes waiting to go to production in the pipe right now and some of them look scary, so I'm gonna do my Saturday night a favor and wait till Monday to deploy.

In the meantime, you should be able to edit your photo from your profile.